# I need to send an id from read component to update component. The id must be obtained by function updateItem(). But id is not sent to the child pag

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component

The id is obtaind correctly by function updateItem(id)

```
<template>
  <UpdateView :itemId="itemId"/>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        {{ item.name }}: {{ item.description }}
        <img :src="item.photo_url" alt="Country Image" />
        <button @click="deleteItem(item.id)">Delete</button>
        <button @click="updateItem(item.id)">Update</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
    import { ref, onMounted, provide } from 'vue'
    import { supabase } from '../supabase'
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
    import UpdateView from './UpdateView.vue'

    const items = ref([])
    const itemId = ref(null)
    const router = useRouter()
  
    provide('itemId', itemId)
  
    async function getItems() {
      const { data } = await supabase.from('tabela1').select()
      items.value = data
    }
  
    async function deleteItem(id) {
      await supabase.from('tabela1').delete().eq('id', id)
      getItems() // Atualiza a lista após deletar o item
    }
  
    function updateItem(id) {
      itemId.value = id
      router.push({ name: 'update' }) // Redireciona para a rota de atualização
      console.log(itemId.value)
    }
  
    onMounted(() => {
      getItems()
    })
  </script>
```

This page must receive the id, but it not happens

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import { supabase } from '../supabase'

  const item = ref(null)
  const props = defineProps({
    itemId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  })

  onMounted(async () => {
    const { data } = await supabase.from('tabela1').select().eq('id', props.itemId.value)
    item.value = data[0]
    console.log(props.itemId)
  })
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="item">
    <label for="name">Nome</label>
    <input id="name" v-model="item.name" />

    <label for="description">Descrição</label>
    <input id="description" v-model="item.description" />

    <button @click="updateItem">Atualizar</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

If I put the number 2 in the place of props.itemId.value in the update page It works corectly, but if I put the number 2 in the place of id in itemId.value = id in the read page, It don't work
I don't know what is happening